# How to make ECS instance exclusive to specific service tasks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-ecs

I have a requirement where I need to run a specific service task to a particular instance type (say r5.large), and I know from service task definition I can add placement constraints and allow the service to run only on those r5.large machines!

But I don't want existing service tasks (and I have so many of them at the moment) which don't have any placement constraints to be scheduled on the r5.instance.

These r5.instance should only schedule jobs which my placement constraint and reject all other services!

The only options I could imagine are :

- Create a separate ECS cluster
- Or add placement Constraints to every other existing service tasks - Which I would not prefer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've outlined the available options correctly.

As far as I know there is no node-level configuration to only allow certain tasks.

If there are only very few different tasks/services on the cluster I'd go for option b), otherwise I'd create a specialized cluster with the larger instances - option a).